# sort a List<int> in c# ignoring the sign

Tags: c#

I have a list as below
    var initial = new List { 2, 5, 6,-1, -3, -4 };

Expected output is {-1,2,-3,-4,5,6} =>(sort the given list by ignoring the -ve sign but not removing them in the result.)

My attempt to solve this is

```
            var initial = new List<string> { 2, 5, 6,-1, -3, -4 };
            var dummyList = initial.FindAll(x => x < 0);

            initial .RemoveAll(x => dummyList.Contains(x));

            foreach (var e in dummyList)
            {
                initial .Add(e * -1);
            }

            initial.Sort();

            foreach (var e in dummyList)
            {
                var index = initial.FindIndex(x=>x==(e*-1));
                initial.RemoveAt(index);
                initial.Insert(index, e);
            }
```

Can someone give a better solution for this.
https://dotnetfiddle.net/gcd1I1
Thanks!

Comment: `initial.OrderBy(x => Math.Abs(x))` ?

Comment: oops it didn't work. :(

Comment: https://dotnetfiddle.net/n9YKNY

Comment: Use the result of that `OrderBy` in your `for`, like `foreach(var e in initial.OrderBy(x => Math.Abs(x))){`

Comment: Great! I assumed that OrderBy() stores the result in the source variable. My bad.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can pass a `Comparison` to `Sort` method, then compare using absolute value:

```
list.Sort((a, b) => Math.Abs(a).CompareTo(Math.Abs(b)));
```

Or using Linq:

```
list = list.OrderBy(x => Math.Abs(x)).ToList();
```